# Java sql - How to insert TimeStamp into a mysql database including milliseconds

Tags: java, mysql, timestamp, milliseconds

How do I convert a Java TimeStamp object to a SQL datetime type that includes milliseconds?
When I insert my TimeStamp obj into the database the milliseconds are gone.

This is my Java source code to translate a String into a Timestamp object:

```
import java.sql.Timestamp;
...
...
String timeStr = "2013-08-30 19:11:49.113";
Timestamp timeCreated = Timestamp.valueOf(timeStr);
timeCreated.toString(); //returns "2013-08-30 19:11:49.113"
```

My table dfinition in SQL:

```
CREATE TABLE `Event` (EventTimeStamp datetime NOT NULL);
```

This is how I insert the TimeStamp object into my Database:

```
PreparedStatement psInsert;
Connection conn = ...
psInsert = conn
            .prepareStatement("INSERT INTO `Event` (EventTimeStamp) VALUES(?)");  

psInsert.setTimestamp(1, timeCreated);
psInsert.executeUpdate();
```

After insertion the TimeStamp is cut and there are no milliseconds anymore:

```
2013-08-30 19:11:49
```

Thx

Comment: how do you check value in database?

Comment: In the MySql Workbench: `SELECT * FROM Event;`

Comment: what version of mysql?

Comment: fractional parts were added in 5.6.4

Comment: Select Version(); says: 5.5.49

Comment: Okay I updated my mysql version and my mysql workbench with this guide: [link] {http://comet.lehman.cuny.edu/jung/cmp420758/guide.pdf} but I did not effect the milliceond problem

Comment: strange, can you insert millis in bench and check the result, to test whether this mysql or java one

Comment: The answer of @Rob below and your advice to update my mysql version did the trick. I had to use `datetime(3)` instead of `datetime`.  `datetime(3)` did not work with my version 5.5.49 but does work now with the version 5.6.3 . Furthermore, `datetime` only does not fix the milliseconds problem in version 5.6.3

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your database column `datetime` has no place for milliseconds. You should use `datetime(3)` instead.

Comment: This did the trick! Thx! But I needed to install the latest mysql version for this solution. @Lashane thx for the advice to update my mysql.